# Use C switch statement for error handling

Tags: c, error-handling, goto

Consider this C construct that checks for errors before doing actual work:

```
int function(struct Context *context,struct Connection *conn)
{
    int retval;

    switch(0)
    {   
        case 0:
            retval = BUFFER_INACTIVE;
            if(conn->mSocket == -1) 
                break;
            retval = BUFFER_FULL;
            /* Is there enough room to add ? */
            if((context->mMaxBufferSize - conn->mSendPacketLength) < aPacketLength)
                break;

            /* Is the send packet buffer half sent? */
            if(conn->mSendPacketLength > 0 && conn->mSendPacketPos != conn->mSendPacket)
                break;

            /* Do some work here */
            retval = BUFFER_DONE;
    }
    /* Do some things before returning */
    printf("%d",retval);
    return retval;
}
```

Would you consider this a being readable? Would the alternatives, using `goto` or stacked `if()` be better?

Comment: I'm really not afraid of gotos... I tough of this construct and wanted some feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen the switch solution, but I've done stuff like this:

```
do {
    err = func();
    if( err ) break;
    err = func2();
    if( err ) break;
    ...
} while( 0 );
if( err ) {
   // handle errors
}
```

But what's the real difference between that and this:

```
err = func();
if( err ) goto done;
err = func2();
if( err ) goto done;
...
done:
if( err ) {
   //handle errors;
}
```

The first is just the second one rewritten to avoid using the keyword `goto`, and I'd argue that the `goto` solution is more readable. It took me a while, but I've managed to convince myself that `goto`s are not *always* evil.

In the end, I prefer just using `if` statements if possible since it makes the code more readable, but `goto`s if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that is less readable.  I think using a if statements or even a goto would be a much more suitable approach.  Using goto's is not the end of the world and is perfectly acceptable and appropriate for error handling.

http://kerneltrap.org/node/553/2131

Comment: I agree that if somebody sees that switch(), it would take some time to decipher what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **while(true)** instead of switch:

```
while(true)
{   
            retval = BUFFER_INACTIVE;
            if(conn->mSocket == -1) 
                    break;
            retval = BUFFER_FULL;
            /* Is there enough room to add ? */
            if((context->mMaxBufferSize - conn->mSendPacketLength) < aPacketLength)
                    break;

            /* Is the send packet buffer half sent? */
            if(conn->mSendPacketLength > 0 && conn->mSendPacketPos != conn->mSendPacket)
                    break;

            /* Do some work here */
            retval = BUFFER_DONE;
            break;
}
```

Comment: I think the while(true) will lead somebody to expect looping, which this definitely does not do.  Using "do { ... } while (0);" is more idiomatic.

Comment: Agree, do { ... } while (0); is better way to do it.

Comment: do { ... while (0); is also the best practice for containing scope in a macro ...

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is wrapping it in a function and returning instead of breaking.  This is often a bad idea since it ends up adding an unnecessary layer of abstraction.  However, in some cases it can make things simpler.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is to use cascaded ifs:

```
u8 u8IsOk;

u8IsOk = Func1();

if(u8IsOk)
{
    /* Do some stuff...*/
    u8IsOk = Func2();
} /* if */

if(u8IsOk)
{
    /* Do some stuff...*/
    u8IsOk = Func3();
} /* if */
```

...and so on. Not as efficient as some other methods, but avoids excessive nesting, goto, break, while(0) and multiple returns.

Comment: I've been surprised how much people seem to dislike it. It's quite common in embedded software.